# Steps to create a start-up service oriented architecture by using php

Tags: soa

Could anyone tell me what steps are required to make a good start-up service oriented architecture for departments, example language department?

Actually, i've mastered much better in PHP codeigniter, JQuery and AJAX. But, i still learn about Codeigniter for e-commerce

Expected output: To give the best result once the web service is developed

Answer (score 0):

First, I am sorry that your question didnt catch up. Perhaps I suggest you should re-formulate the question.

SOA as such involves some initial strategic effort to achieve a good service oriented design and a stable implementation plan. Please refer to the [SOA MAnifesto](http://serviceorientation.com/soamanifesto/original) to get an insight of the defined service orientation principles and the outcome of SOA as an application of the principles to help organization achieve agility, return on investment, increased federation, reduced IT burden and a standardisation of business logic.

the second paragraph has nothing to do with the question as it mentions different technologies. there is a good reference for writing [PHP apps with SOA focus](https://www.phproundtable.com/episode/service-oriented-architecture-and-microservices).

from your expected output goal. That goal cant be measured. what do you defined as "best  result"? why do you mention only a web service?

Please re-write the question so you can approach your problem in a rather more efficient manner.